# Why doesn't array_merge reproduce the same effect as multiple json_encodes

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have three arrays I want to merge together. All of these arrays are the exact same just with different data inside of them, each array has 50 items, each item has an object called tags etc.

My question is how come I get a different response when I try to merge these together and then echo them out as JSON, than just echoing them out as JSON separately.

```
$tagArrays = array_merge($tags,$tags2,$tags3);
echo json_encode($tagArrays, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Gives me different results to

```
echo json_encode($tags, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo json_encode($tags2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo json_encode($tags3, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

When I say 'different results' I mean massively different, it seems like the $tags[i] aren't being merged but instead being squashed because they're using the same data. I want them to merge similar to how JSON_encoding them separately works.

In case this helps, Here is what the array looks like (shortened, imagine 50x of the item objects per array, then starting again)

```
{
"kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
"etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0\/azpEKHAfo4vur0hbABsjIPqPgs4\"",
"pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 50,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
},
"items": [
    {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0\/s4gzHDOQRXGUOFPB3RmkIjdbdZI\"",
        "id": "9LuptlmRH6k",
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2016-10-01T20:21:36.000Z",
            "channelId": "UC1e6iW4ojbhn0gUCyvjawKg",
            "title": "\u25ba STORM OF STEEL! - Battlefield 1 - 12 Minutes of Single Player Gameplay",
            "description": "Battlefield 1's single player prologue, Storm of Steel! EA gave me this footage when attending a behind closed doors event at TwitchCon\n\u25ba SUBSCRIBE: http:\/\/bit.ly\/WestieSub\n\nConnect with me on other social sites:\n\n\u25ba TWITTER: http:\/\/bit.ly\/WestieTweet\n\u25ba INSTAGRAM: http:\/\/bit.ly\/InstaWestie\n\u25ba FACEBOOK: http:\/\/bit.ly\/WestieFB\n\u25ba TWITCH: http:\/\/bit.ly\/WestieTwitch\n\n\u25ba My PC Specs: http:\/\/bit.ly\/WestiePC\n\nTheWestie4321 - Westie - MrProWestie\n\n======================================\n\nWell done for reaching the bottom of the description! :D",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/9LuptlmRH6k\/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/9LuptlmRH6k\/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/9LuptlmRH6k\/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                },
                "standard": {
                    "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/9LuptlmRH6k\/sddefault.jpg",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 480
                },
                "maxres": {
                    "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/9LuptlmRH6k\/maxresdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 1280,
                    "height": 720
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "Westie",
            "tags": [
                "Battlefield 1",
                "BF1",
                "Battlefield 1 Multiplayer Gameplay",
                "BF1 gameplay",
                "Battlefield 1 gameplay",
                "Battlefield 1 single player",
                "bf1 single player",
                "battlefield 1 war stories",
                "bf1 war stories",
                "battlefield 1 single player gameplay",
                "bf1 single player gameplay",
                "battlefield 1 campaign",
                "bf1 campaign",
                "battlefield 1 campaign gameplay",
                "bf1 campaign gameplay",
                "storm of steel",
                "battlefield 1 storm of steel",
                "bf1 storm of steel",
                "prologue",
                "battlefield 1 prologue"
            ],
            "categoryId": "20",
            "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
            "localized": {
                "title": "\u25ba STORM OF STEEL! - Battlefield 1 - 12 Minutes of Single Player Gameplay",
                "description": "Battlefield 1's single player prologue, Storm of Steel! EA gave me this footage when attending a behind closed doors event at TwitchCon\n\u25ba SUBSCRIBE: http:\/\/bit.ly\/WestieSub\n\nConnect with me on other social sites:\n\n\u25ba TWITTER: http:\/\/bit.ly\/WestieTweet\n\u25ba INSTAGRAM: http:\/\/bit.ly\/InstaWestie\n\u25ba FACEBOOK: http:\/\/bit.ly\/WestieFB\n\u25ba TWITCH: http:\/\/bit.ly\/WestieTwitch\n\n\u25ba My PC Specs: http:\/\/bit.ly\/WestiePC\n\nTheWestie4321 - Westie - MrProWestie\n\n======================================\n\nWell done for reaching the bottom of the description! :D"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0\/pIBDE20R99Or_-HdZL2sBavValY\"",
        "id": "_8Zbs0qFPv4",
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2016-10-01T21:47:19.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCw7FkXsC00lH2v2yB5LQoYA",
            "title": "BATTLEFIELD 1 SINGLE PLAYER GAMEPLAY",
            "description": "BATTLEFIELD 1 SINGLE PLAYER GAMEPLAY - 12 Minutes of footage from the Battlefield 1 Single Player campaign... Enjoy and let me know your thoughts in the comments below! Leave a rating! Sponsored by: http:\/\/scan.co.uk\/\n\n http:\/\/www.twitter.com\/jackfrags\nhttp:\/\/www.twitch.tv\/jackfrags\nhttp:\/\/www.facebook.com\/jackfragsofficial",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/_8Zbs0qFPv4\/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/_8Zbs0qFPv4\/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/_8Zbs0qFPv4\/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                },
                "standard": {
                    "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/_8Zbs0qFPv4\/sddefault.jpg",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 480
                },
                "maxres": {
                    "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/_8Zbs0qFPv4\/maxresdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 1280,
                    "height": 720
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "jackfrags",
            "tags": [
                "BATTLEFIELD 1 SINGLE PLAYER GAMEPLAY",
                "BATTLEFIELD 1 SINGLE PLAYER",
                "battlefield 1"
            ],
            "categoryId": "20",
            "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
            "localized": {
                "title": "BATTLEFIELD 1 SINGLE PLAYER GAMEPLAY",
                "description": "BATTLEFIELD 1 SINGLE PLAYER GAMEPLAY - 12 Minutes of footage from the Battlefield 1 Single Player campaign... Enjoy and let me know your thoughts in the comments below! Leave a rating! Sponsored by: http:\/\/scan.co.uk\/\n\n http:\/\/www.twitter.com\/jackfrags\nhttp:\/\/www.twitch.tv\/jackfrags\nhttp:\/\/www.facebook.com\/jackfragsofficial"
            },
            "defaultAudioLanguage": "en-GB"
        }
    },
```

How can I stop the merging squishing the arrays and add them together?

EDIT: My end goal involves me being able to use `while ($i < 150)` (from all the items in one array, rather than using `while ($i < 50)` three times

Comment: Please provide some example data to strengthen your question

Comment: Doing it now @RobbieAverill

Comment: because `array_merge` will merge arrays by order from first, if second array have same key as first then value from first will be used in result array

Comment: Sorry Conor, I should've been more clear - can you share an example of what `$tags`, `$tags2, `$tags3` look like? Putting them into something like https://eval.in would be useful so properly reproduce your problem

Comment: you misunderstood what `array_merge` does.. if you do `json_encode([$tags, $tags2, $tags3], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` i think you get what you want

Comment: @RobbieAverill In the answer is what Tags(i) looks like, I'll quickly upload the full arrays to the site you linked - Here is the link https://eval.in/654436

Comment: @MarekJanoud Testing now! :)

Comment: Okay @MarekJanoud This works up to the point of them being separate objects which is fine if that's the only way. But my end goal was more of to stop using `while ($i < 50)` three times and use `while ($i < 150)` ill update my question to include this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really like answering my own questions, especially for a simple mistake like this but the problem I had was the fact that I misunderstood what I was trying to do. When it was made clear to me by @MarekJanoud it allowed me to do a little more research to find that `array_merge_recursive` allows me to merge all of the arrays into one allowing me to use the data and I originally wanted to.

Thank you @MarekJanoud

Comment: @MarekJanoud Which part?

Comment: which result you want to achieve, btw with `array_merge_recursive` the subarrays may not be in same order, like `kind[1]` dont match with `etag[1]` if for example `$tags2` dont have `etag`  key and `$tags3` do have

Comment: `$tags = ['kind' => 'kind tags', 'etag' => 'etag tags'];
$tags2 = ['kind' => 'kind tags2'];
$tags3 = ['kind' => 'kind tags3', 'etag' => 'etag tags3'];

$result = array_merge_recursive($tags, $tags2, $tags3);

echo $result['kind'][1] . ' not belong to ' . $result['etag'][1];`

Comment: pls let me know you know about this

Comment: I've implemented using `array_merge_recursive()` into my program and it's now working as I expected it to, I actually only used `$result[$i]` and didn't need them to relate any objects to each other at all which made it suit my program

Answer (score 1):

i dont see any while in the code... but this could do the work:

```
$result = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){
    for($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++){
        $var = 'tags'.($j>1?$j:'');
        $result[] = $$var;
    }
}

json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

this will add `$tags` to `$result` then `$tags2` then `$tags3` and again 50 times